# Multiple instances of Tiny Carousel on single page

Tags: carousel, tiny-carousel

I'm using the plugin Tiny Carousel (http://baijs.nl/tinycarousel), but I can't find a way to get multiple instances to work on a single page - the website seems to lack documentation on this.

I have my example up at a server. As you can see, only the first instances is working: http://irishhuddle.com/RSS/slider/slidertest.html.

How can I modify my HTML and .js file to make this work? I know similar questions have been asked... I have spend a lot of time reading them, but can't find a way to apply the same principles to my code.

My js file:

```js
(function($){
$.tiny = $.tiny || { };

$.tiny.carousel = {
    options: {  
        start: 1, // where should the carousel start?
        display: 1, // how many blocks do you want to move at 1 time?
        axis: 'x', // vertical or horizontal scroller? ( x || y ).
        controls: true, // show left and right navigation buttons.
        pager: false, // is there a page number navigation present?
        interval: false, // move to another block on intervals.
        animation: true, // false is instant, true is animate.
        duration: 500, // how fast must the animation move in ms?
        callback: null // function that executes after every move.
    }
};

$.fn.tinycarousel = function(options) {
    var options = $.extend({}, $.tiny.carousel.options, options);
    this.each(function(){ $(this).data('tcl', new Carousel($(this), options)); });
    return this;
};
$.fn.tinycarousel_move = function(iNum){ $(this).data('tcl').move(iNum-1,true); };

function Carousel(root, options){
    var oSelf = this;
    var oViewport = $('.viewport:first', root);
    var oContent = $('.overview:first', root);
    var oPages = oContent.children();
    var oBtnNext = $('.next:first', root);
    var oBtnPrev = $('.prev:first', root);
    var oPager = $('.pager:first', root);
    var iPageSize, iSteps, iCurrent, oTimer, bPause, bForward = true, bAxis = options.axis == 'x';

    function initialize(){
        iPageSize = bAxis ? $(oPages[0]).outerWidth(true) : $(oPages[0]).outerHeight(true);
        var iLeftover = Math.ceil(((bAxis ? oViewport.outerWidth() : oViewport.outerHeight()) / (iPageSize * options.display)) -1);
        iSteps = Math.max(1, Math.ceil(oPages.length / options.display) - iLeftover);
        iCurrent = Math.min(iSteps, Math.max(1, options.start)) -2;
        oContent.css(bAxis ? 'width' : 'height', (iPageSize * oPages.length));
        oSelf.move(1);
        setEvents();
        return oSelf;
    };
    function setEvents(){
        if(options.controls && oBtnPrev.length > 0 && oBtnNext.length > 0){
            oBtnPrev.click(function(){oSelf.move(-1); return false;});
            oBtnNext.click(function(){oSelf.move( 1); return false;});
        }
        if(options.interval){ root.hover(oSelf.stop,oSelf.start); }
        if(options.pager && oPager.length > 0){ $('a',oPager).click(setPager); }
    };
    function setButtons(){
        if(options.controls){
            oBtnPrev.toggleClass('disable', !(iCurrent > 0));
            oBtnNext.toggleClass('disable', !(iCurrent +1 < iSteps));
        }
        if(options.pager){
            var oNumbers = $('.pagenum', oPager);
            oNumbers.removeClass('active');
            $(oNumbers[iCurrent]).addClass('active');
            document.getElementById('slidenum').innerHTML = iCurrent+1;             
        }           
    };

    this.move = function(iDirection, bPublic){
        iCurrent = bPublic ? iDirection : iCurrent += iDirection;
        if(iCurrent > -1 && iCurrent < iSteps){
            var oPosition = {};
            oPosition[bAxis ? 'left' : 'top'] = -(iCurrent * (iPageSize * options.display));    
            oContent.animate(oPosition,{
                queue: false,
                duration: options.animation ? options.duration : 0,
                complete: function(){
                    if(typeof options.callback == 'function')
                    options.callback.call(this, oPages[iCurrent], iCurrent);
                }
            });
            setButtons();
        }
    };
    return initialize();
};
})(jQuery);
```

---

UPDATE: My HTML now looks like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">         
    $(document).ready(function(){               

        $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ pager: true });
        $('#slider-code2').tinycarousel({ pager: true });

    });
    </script>

<div id="slider-code">
  <div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
      <li><a rel="1" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 1</a></li>
      <li><a rel="2" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 2</a></li>
      <li><a rel="3" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 3</a></li>
      <li><a rel="4" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 4</a></li>
      <li><a rel="5" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 5</a></li>
      <li><a rel="6" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 6</a></li>       
      </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="pager">
   <li><a href="#" class="buttons prev">left</a></li>
  <li id="slidenum">1</li><li> / 6</li>
  <li><a href="#" class="buttons next">right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider-code2">
  <div class="viewport">
      <ul class="overview">
      <li><a rel="1" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 1</a></li>
      <li><a rel="2" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 2</a></li>
      <li><a rel="3" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 3</a></li>
      <li><a rel="4" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 4</a></li>
      <li><a rel="5" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 5</a></li>
      <li><a rel="6" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 6</a></li>       
      </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="pager">
   <li><a href="#" class="buttons prev">left</a></li>
  <li id="slidenum">1</li><li> / 6</li>
  <li><a href="#" class="buttons next">right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to call `$('#slider1').tinycarousel();` on your other slider

In you case, something like: `$('#slider-code').tinycarousel();` and `$('#slider-code2').tinycarousel();`

that should be all

**EDIT**

Just a quick fix for your html:

```html
<div id="slider-code">
  <div class="viewport">
    <ul class="overview">
      <li><a rel="1" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 1</a></li>
      <li><a rel="2" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 2</a></li>
      <li><a rel="3" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 3</a></li>
      <li><a rel="4" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 4</a></li>
      <li><a rel="5" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 5</a></li>
      <li><a rel="6" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 6</a></li>       
      </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="pager">
   <li><a href="#" class="buttons prev">left</a></li>
  <li id="slidenum">1</li><li> / 6</li>
  <li><a href="#" class="buttons next">right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="slider-code2">
  <div class="viewport">
      <ul class="overview">
      <li><a rel="1" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 1</a></li>
      <li><a rel="2" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 2</a></li>
      <li><a rel="3" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 3</a></li>
      <li><a rel="4" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 4</a></li>
      <li><a rel="5" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 5</a></li>
      <li><a rel="6" class="pagenum" href="#">Hi 6</a></li>       
      </ul>
  </div>

  <ul class="pager">
   <li><a href="#" class="buttons prev">left</a></li>
  <li id="slidenum">1</li><li> / 6</li>
  <li><a href="#" class="buttons next">right</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think I made the changes, but I'm still having the same problem. (my test site: irishhuddle.com/RSS/slider/slidertest.html ) Sorry for the trouble... I updated my first post so it now has my current HTML.

Comment: yeah, sorry for the delay. thanks for the responses. i had to make $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ pager: true }); so it was just $('#slider-code').tinycarousel();

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by turning the `#slider-code` into an HTML class, `.slider-code`. Apply that change to the CSS and caller function. Then name all your instances `.slider-code`.